# How would I mention someone In Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to be able to mention a user when they join the server I really need help with this.

Comment: please, share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

For user mentions it is the user's ID with <@ at the start and > at the end,
like this:
<@17372382352635>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it I will help some of you guys so when you are making it put the tilda key instead of ''.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the following method [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) from Discord.js

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async (guild_member) => {
  //message.send with notification, for `guild_member.user.username`
})
```

You may also find [the example code, in the repo of my own Discord bot](https://github.com/AlexZeDim/rainy/blob/master/bot.js), which is actually check (for proper names) and renaming users, on server join event.

My personal advice, not to use DM (because users may have forbid to receive messages from non-friends and members of the mutual discord server.

And as was mentioned before, by Dpk, you may use `<@idOfUser/Channel/Whatever>` to create a link or mention or any other thing via it's ID.